# Valor de todos los select se repite al momento de seleccionar el valor de un select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Este es mi código html

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">ID</th>
                    <th class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">Numero de solicitud</th>
                    <th class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">Fecha de Captura</th>
                    <th class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">Objeto Particular</th>
                    <th class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">Responsable</th>
                    <th class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo">Estatus</th>
                    <th class="tamañoLetraTablaTitulo"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-init="ctrl.configPages()" ng-repeat="x in ctrl.SolicitudDetalle | startFromGrid: ctrl.currentPage * ctrl.pageSize | limitTo: ctrl.pageSize">
                    <td><a id="editSol" ng-click="ctrl.getParametros(x.Id)">{{x.Id}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{x.Num_Solicitud}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.FechaCaptura}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.ObjPart}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Responsable}}</td>
                    <td><select ng-model="ctrl.Status" @*ng-options="obj.Descripcion for obj in ctrl.ListaStatus track by option + obj.Id"*@ ng-options="obj.Descripcion for obj in ctrl.ListaStatus track by obj.Id">
                            <option value="">---SELECCIONE---</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><input ng-click="ctrl.SetParametrosSolicitar(x.Id, Status.Id)" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Confirmar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal" /></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

[image: Al momento de seleccionar un elemento de un select me cambia el valor de todos, como puedo evitar eso]

Comment: Todos los select apuntan al mismo *modelo*, necesitarías crear uno para cada fila

Comment: Sabes como puedo asignar un modelo distinto para cada select?

Comment: Y si el ng-model en lugar de ser un objeto lo conviertes en un array de objetos? Podrías utilizar el indice para indicar la posición. algo asi `ng-model="ctrl.Status[obj.Id]"`